# Is possible to achieve inserted row's Id that added by EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table in EF that in it `Id` column is PK and `Auto_Increment`. I use this code to insert a row to table:

```
 Cut newCut = new Cut()
        {
            Name = name,
            Comments = comments
        };

 context.Cuts.AddObject(newCut);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Is possible to achieve added row's `Id` without another query?

Comment: Excuse me for this beginner question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try `newCut.Id` *after* `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

When you save changes, your `Cut` instance automatically populates with new `Id` by entity framework. So after `SaveChanges()` you can call `newCut.Id`.